# Why doesn't background url work with svg files in webpack?

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

**webpack.base.config.js:**

```
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const path = require('path');

const resolve = dir => path.join(__dirname, '..', dir);

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './src/index.js',
  },
  output: {
    path: resolve('dist'),
    filename: 'js/[name].[hash].js',
    publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '/' : '/',
  },
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        vendor: {
          chunks:'initial',
          name: 'vendor',
          test: 'vendor',
          enforce: true,
        },
      },
    },
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.json'],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        enforce: 'pre',
        use: {
          loader: 'eslint-loader',
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'html-loader',
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
            },
          },
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
            },
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: '[hash]-[name].[ext]',
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(mp4|webm|ogg|mp3|wav|flac|aac)(\?.*)?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: '[hash]-[name].[ext]'
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: '[name]-[hash].[ext]',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

I write in css like this:

```
.icon {
  width: 4.2rem;
  height: 5.3rem;
  background: url('../img/icon.svg') left top no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

And instead of the icon, this is what happens:

```
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,bW9kdWxlLmV4cG9ydHMgPSBfX3dlYnBhY2tfcHVibGljX3BhdGhfXyArICJpY29uLWRvYy1hNjk0NTdkY2IzZWQ1OWVhZmZhZjE4MDA3MTkwNWI1Yi5zdmciOw==) left top no-repeat
```

The project structure is as follows:

```
project
--public
----index.html
--src
----assets
------img
--------icon.svg
------scss
--------icons.scss (тут и пишу)
----components
----views
----...
```

**Question:** with this config, the import inside jsx works fine, both dev mode and in sale. But the background url does not work, that is, the SVG picture is not visible, everything is fine with PNG.

Answer (score 0):

In this code you are telling webpack to translate the **svg** images to **base64** with the `url-loader` module

```
{
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: '[hash]-[name].[ext]',
        },
      }
```

That should really work...

### I suggest you try the following:

Try inserting the svg directly into your html, where the icon should be. Do it so that you can reuse it, such as creating an icon component, which is at the end of this form, in the DOM:

*for example*

```
<div class="my-icon">
  <svg><path/></svg>
</div>
```

If you insert it as html it will work

Comment: Thx for help, but i'm use eslint-airbnb-config and if i do what you say, i get a bunch of errors. http://prntscr.com/lj208w